Linear regression applied to time series with trend - how to deal with it and how to interpret results?
I need to fit a linear regression model on time series. For simplicity, let's assume that we have only three variables:

Y -  has visible trend; after differencing is stationary
X1 - has visible trend; after differencing is stationary
X2 - is stationary.

I see three options here:

original Y vs original X1 and X2 - can lead to spurious regression
original Y vs diff(X1), X2 - correlations between target and Xs are low => really low $R^2$
diff(Y) vs diff(X1), X2 - I don't know how to interpret regression coefficient in this case.

What should I do? Option 3 seems like the correct approach to me but I don't know how to intepret coefficients - it is important because it is an econometric model and I should be able to draw some conclusions about the nature of modelled phenomenon. Note that in the real project there are 8 independent variables (X1, ... X8), not two. Some of them are stationary and some are after differencing.
Edit: I just came up with Option 4 - original Y vs diff(X1), X2 and time variable. I am not sure if it makes sense, I am going to try and examine the fitted model. My intuition is that it will lead to the model with only significant coefficients being intercept and time.

You write "I need to fit a linear regression model" why do you need to do this? Why not time series methods?  As to how to do it .... very carefully.

@PeterFlom I need to because it's part of a project with aim to learn linear regression

If you want to learn linear regression, don't use time series data. That's for very expert people.

@PeterFlom I already know quite a lot about linear regression, the goal is to learn linear regression with time series data specifically

Dang.  That's not a good goal. But, I guess you didn't set the goal. Good luck.
